# PHP - using namespaces in namespaced files with PSR-4 autoload composer

Tags: php, composer-php

The issue I am experiencing is when I call to the class MySpices method getSpice I get nothing, no errors, no response.
I have the feeling the problem is within the use namespaces.  All other classes’ works fine, except for this class MySpices which is the only file that extends. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Here's a sample of my dirs and files:

```
    // files and directories
    site.com
      |-meatballs
      | |--src
      | |    |-app
      | |    |-errors
      | |    |-include
      | |    |-library
      | |        |-MySpices.php
      | |        |-SpiceFac.php
      | |        |--more files
      | |--vendor
      | |    |-composer
      | |    |-autoload.php
      | |
      | composer.json
      |
    index.php
```

The composer.json file includes:

```
    {
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "meatballs\\": "src/"
            }
        }
    }
```

FileName: MySpices.php

```
    namespace meatballs\library
    {
      use meatballs\library as QDSE;

      class MySpices extends QDSE\SpiceFac
      {
        protected $_spice;

        function __construct()
        {
          parent::__construct();

          $this->_spice = 'ginger';
          // more codes

        }

        public function getSpice()
        {
            return $this->_spice;
        }
      }
    }
```

FileName: SpiceFac.php

```
    namespace meatballs\library
    {
      class SpiceFac
      {
        protected $_spices;

        function __construct()
        {
           // some codes here       
        }

        private function spiceList()
        {
            // spices  arrays
            $this->_spaces = $spices;
        }

        public function getSpices()
        {
            return $this->_spaces;
        }

        // other class methods
      }
    }
```

The index.php page

```
    // get the apps autoload file
    $loadFiles = '../vendor/autoload.php';

    // check if autoloader file exist
    if(file_exists($loadFiles))
        require_once $loadFiles;

    // use namespace
    use meatballs\library\SpiceFac;
    use meatballs\library\MySpices;

    $mySpice = new MySpices();
    $taste = $mySpice->getSpice();

    echo $taste . "<br />";
```

Comment: Issue found and was corrected

Comment: so you have found the problem, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Adding an alias name to the use namespace resolved the issue with the class MySpice.